# Restsharp raise SSL error when run on server

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, restsharp

I am using Restsharp request to an API and codes are blow:

```
var client = new RestClient(baseURL);
var request = new RestRequest(url);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", authHeader);

var response = client.Get<T>(request);
return response;
```

Same code did not raise any error on my test enviroment, but when I run the code on server, I get following error:

```
error message    : The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
exception        : System.Net.WebException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

I don't know what is wrong with that code and I don't understand why same codes run differently?

Any help for fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the service pointed by baseURL has invalid SSL certificate.
You can bypass SSL validation check by adding the following line of code before making the call.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

This globally disables SSL validation. It will totally work fine even if the production service has valid SSL, but it will certainly introduce some vulnerability in your code. You can wrap it inside

```
#if DEBUG
#endif
```

Comment: I know this can help but same code is ok when I run on my local devices. If the url has invalid SSL, why it does not raise error on my local ?

Comment: Do you get any prompt message before proceeding to site when you directly browse the baseURL in your browser?

Comment: Nope. Here is the url I want to reach : https://api.astroprint.com/jobs

Comment: I am seeing the prompt message. Seems like you have already browsed the URL and clicked on 

Advanced > Proceed to api.astroprint.com (unsafe)

So you won't get any error. But if you try browsing it new incognito/private window you'll get the prompt message. If you see on the browser, you'll still see "not secure" labelled.